# DPM 2012 recovery point always shows "0KB used"

Tags: scdpm

Quick question - why does it always show 0KB used against each of our protected volumes on DPM 2012? My understanding is that the replica volume contains the current full replica of the volume (F: drive in this case) and the recovery point contains the historical recovery points made - 15 of them in this case. 245GB is about right for the size of the recovery point over 5 days but it always says 0 KB used which is worrying. Although it appears to be working fine, i.e. one can restore back over 5 days.

[image: DPM recovery point]

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug.  It only affects the GUI and can be safely ignored.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c6036b71-b6fc-48e7-ab93-69e6e8466b0f/dpm-2012-r2-reporting-incorrect-recovery-point-allocatedused-space?forum=dataprotectionmanager